# python sort on timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, sorting

I have a bunch of records for which I calculate timedelta (latest - time of creation). I need to sort them so that the latest comes first. I do it like this -

```
results = list()
for i in range(100):
    res.append((name, content, delta, age))
res = sorted(res, key=lambda i:i[2], reverse=True)
```

This would work perfect, but in some cases my delta object is `None`. so my `lambda` fn. is spitting out errors. Any way to fix this?

```
...
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to NoneType
```

**UPDATE: The records with `None` deltas should move to the end.**

Comment: the main question is: what should happen with a record where `delta` is `None`?

Comment: the `None` should move to the end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, before you append the tuple to `res`, check if `delta` is `None` - if it is, set it to some sort of default based on where you'd like empty deltas to end up (either the front or the back).

Comment: I know that, but what is that "default" val based on ?

Comment: You could base it on anything - the highest or lowest delta in the list, or 2001 - 1967, or anything else - it's up to you based on where you want your None deltas to end up.

Comment: @MovieYoda: It is based on wheter you want None values to move to the beginning or the end of your list

Answer (score 4):

You want None to compare less than ALL possible timedelta values, even negative ones. So what you do is augment your key with a leading flag:

```
key=lambda i: (i[2] is not None, i[2])
```

Thus `None` is compared as `(False, None)` and `some_timedelta` is compared as `(True, some_timedelta)` and there's no chance of the non-comparable types being mixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
res = sorted(filter(lambda t: t is not None, res), key=lambda i:i[2], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Sure it will. You didn't state that it was necessary to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare_time( item ):
    delta = item[2]
    return timedelta(days=365*100) if delta is None else delta # 100 years
```